# How can I access property/mapping-attributes when implementing my own IUserType

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have implemented my own type `PaddedString`, which is used like this in the mapping-xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"
      encoding="utf-8"?>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="MyAssembly"
                   namespace="MyNamespace">
  <class name="MyClass">
    <!-- id is omitted here -->
    <property name="MyProperty"
              length="300"
              type="TypeNamespace.PaddedString, TypeAssembly"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

So, I have followed [this great code-project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/504212/Working-with-legacy-databases-in-NHibernate-Part) to implement my `TrimmedString`, and I thought I could use this as a guideline to my `PaddedString`:

```
public sealed class PaddedString : IUserType,
                                   IEnhancedUserType
{
    // I am leaving out all the other methods, because NullSafeGet is the only one with the "real" logic
    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs,
                              string[] names,
                              object owner)
    {
        var obj = NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeGet(rs,
                                                    names[0]);

        var length = 300; // How do I read the attribute `length` of the mapping in here?

        if (obj == null)
        {
            return new string(' ',
                              length);
        }

        return obj.ToString()
                  .PadRight(length,
                            ' ');
    }
}
```

The needed part is quite clear: How do I read the attribute `length` of the mapping? Or do you know any other approach to inject a length in `PaddedString`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this by incorporate `IParameterizedType` like:

```
public sealed class PaddedString : IUserType,
                                   IEnhancedUserType,
                                   IParameterizedType
{
    private int Length { get; set; }

    public void SetParameterValues(IDictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
        this.Length = int.Parse(parameters["length"]);
    }

    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs,
                              string[] names,
                              object owner)
    {
        var obj = NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeGet(rs,
                                                    names[0]);

        if (obj == null)
        {
            return new string(' ',
                              this.Length);
        }

        return obj.ToString()
                  .PadRight(this.Length,
                            ' ');
    }
}
```

Which I then used like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"
      encoding="utf-8"?>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="MyAssembly"
                   namespace="MyNamespace">
  <class name="MyClass">
    <!-- id is omitted here -->
    <property name="MyProperty">
        <type name="TypeNamespace.PaddedString, TypeAssembly">
            <param name="length">300</length>
        </type>
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: *JUST a very small note: I wouldn't go this way... Never. I believe in layers. And data layer should just persist what the business layer sends. The business should be responsible for "string property" validation or trimming or padding... BUT, I like how you are playing with NHibernate ;) It is (used to be) a great, awesome tool*

Comment: @RadimKöhler the problem is that I have no real business logic here... I just have an access-database which is updated by a VB6-program - so I am going for the "always validate/ensure user-input"-paradigm here (as I do not have control over the accuracy of the population in the VB6-program). And, if that wasn't enough, I am also dealing with a non-normalized database, where I need to do a lot of `.Substring`-calls to split columns into multiple properties ... So the easiest way to ensure a certain length (to not fail any calls) is a custom type ...

Comment: @RadimKöhler and ... after all ... this is just part of a small conversion-program, which will not be running constantly live ... But you know the ugly thruth, when you have to deal with *any* input provided and just want to do as less work as needed for the task ... ;)

Comment: I am not judging. Just had to append some more comment, then simple upvote. I do admire that you do play with NHibernate. That is great. really. Good luck with that amazing tool ;)